# Having issues reading and loading config into custom objects in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im trying to read the config and populate the custom objects, but I only get *LCTools* but not *LCLog*.

I've tried to use `.GetSection("LCTools:LCLog")`

**appsettings.json**:

```
{   
  "LCTools": {
    "LCLog": {
      "AppId": 1
    }   
  }
}
```

**Where I read and load config**:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseLCLog(this IApplicationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    ILCToolsOptions options = configuration.GetSection("LCTools").GetSection("LCLog").Get<_LCToolsOptions>();
    LogManager.Configuration = LCLog.Utility.GetConfiguration(options);
    ILoggerFactory factory = builder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

    factory.AddNLog();
    factory.AddProvider(new DbLCLogProvider(options.LCLogOptions.Filter, configuration));           

    return builder;
}
```

**Classes**:

```
public interface ILCLogBase
{
    Func<string, LogLevel, bool> Filter { get; set; }
}

public abstract class LCLogBase : ILCLogBase
{
    public Func<string, LogLevel, bool> Filter { get; set; }
}

public interface ILCToolsOptions
{
    ILCLogOptions LCLogOptions { get; set; }
}

public class _LCToolsOptions : LCLogBase, ILCToolsOptions
{
    public ILCLogOptions LCLogOptions { get; set; }
}

public interface ILCLogOptions : ILCLogBase
{
    int AppId { get; set; }
    string FileName { get; set; }
    string FileLogLevel { get; set; }
    string DbLogLevel { get; set; }
    string MicrosoftLevel { get; set; }
    string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class LCLogOptions : LCLogBase, ILCLogOptions
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; } = "${basedir}/_Log/${shortdate}.log";
    public string FileLogLevel { get; set; } = "Trace";
    public string DbLogLevel { get; set; } = "Warn";
    public string MicrosoftLevel { get; set; } = "Trace";
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = Utility.ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: It should work, from what I can see. But I wanted to note that I edited your `.GetSection("LCTools::LCLog")` to use a single colon, assuming it was a typo. The double-colon doesn't mean anything with config sections. Maybe try casting the results of the `Get<>` (or add `as ILCToolsOptions` after the Get).

Comment: Also you can confirm a `GetSection()` is valid by checking `Children().Any() == true` (since you say you don't get _LCLog_). But given the json and the code you posted, either approach should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem looks like a misunderstanding of how config builder populates option classes. Configuration API while reading all config sources, internally populates a collection of key-values (simply `Dictionary<string, string>`), where a key is a config param name with `:` used as a delimiter). For your json file that dictionary contains one item `{"LCTools:LCLog:AppId": "1"}`

```
configuration.GetSection("LCTools").GetSection("LCLog").Get<_LCToolsOptions>();
```

The above code means to configuration builder the following: use from dictionary only items with key started from `LCTools:LCLog`, take all available configs and map them to public properties of `_LCToolsOptions` class using remaining key part for mapping.

Configuration builder doesn't do data deserialization. Instead, it constructs option class using default constructor without any parameters and then tries to set public properties for that class using taken key-values from the specified config path.

And you have nothing as result cause your `LCTools:LCLog` section has `AppId` key-value, but `_LCToolsOptions` class doesn't provide `AppId` public property.

---

If you want to construct option class from data in `LCTools:LCLog` section, you should build the `LCLogOptions` instance from `.GetSection("LCLog")` section:

```
    var options = configuration.GetSection("LCTools")
                               .GetSection("LCLog")
                               .Get<LCLogOptions>();
```

as properties like `AppId` are defined in `LCLogOptions`.

---

If you want to build an instance of `_LCToolsOptions`, then you need to modify your option class to:

```
public class _LCToolsOptions : LCLogBase, ILCToolsOptions
{
    public ILCLogOptions LCLog { get; set; }
    // instead of
    // public ILCLogOptions LCLogOptions { get; set; }
}
```

note, that type need to be changed from interface to specific class, and property name (`LCLog`) should reflect the name used in JSON config file.

and then do

```
var options = configuration.GetSection("LCTools").Get<_LCToolsOptions>();
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to explain it. makes more sense now